# Koma Script and formatting glossaries and lists

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, glossaries, tocloft

Can I typeset: table of contents, bibliography, list of figures and indexes using sans serif font and body text using serif fonts?

SOLUTION (?)

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalsize\sffamily}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries \sffamily}


\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\normalsize\sffamily} 

\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{ \sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{ \sffamily}  
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{ \sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{ \sffamily}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started. If you have a question, please use the help menu (``?'') on the top bar to search for help or ask us a question. 

\section{Some examples to get started}

First you have to upload the image file from your computer using the upload link the project menu. Then use the includegraphics command to include it in your document. Use the figure environment and the caption command to add a number and a caption to your figure. See the code for Figure \ref{fig:frog} in this section for an example.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:frog}This frog was uploaded via the project menu.}
\end{figure}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures


\end{document}
```

brings desired effect.

Any better solutions are welcome!

Comment: KOMA and `tocloft` do not like each other. Where's the KOMA content in your `fragment` at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know it's rather simple solution, bo so far it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no index and no bibliography in your example. So here is only a suggestion for the TOC and the lists like LOF and LOT, which are controlled by KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`:

```
\BeforeStartingTOC{\sffamily\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}}
```

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\BeforeStartingTOC{\sffamily\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{An example image\label{fig:example}}
\end{figure}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```